RepeatButton on MahApps Metro: how do I change the background when mousehover?
Here's my Slider:
<Slider x:Name="videoPlayerSlider"
        Minimum="0"
        Maximum="100"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        Thumb.DragStarted="OnSliderDragStarted_Click"
        Thumb.DragDelta="OnSliderDragDelta_Drag"
        Thumb.DragCompleted="OnSliderDragCompleted_Click"
        Value="50"
        Height="20"
        Margin="0,0,0,-20">
    <Slider.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Slider">
            <Grid>
                <Track x:Name="PART_Track">
                    <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                        <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource CustomRepeatButtonStyle}" Command="{x:Static Slider.DecreaseLarge}"
                                      CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                      Focusable="false" />
                    </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <Track.Thumb>
                        <Thumb Style="{StaticResource CustomThumbStyle}" />
                    </Track.Thumb>
                    <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                        <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource CustomRepeatButtonStyle}" Command="{x:Static Slider.IncreaseLarge}"
                                      CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                      Focusable="false" />
                    </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                </Track>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Slider.Template>
</Slider>

And that's the Style applied:
<Style x:Key="CustomThumbStyle"
       TargetType="Thumb">
    <Setter Property="Width"
            Value="10" />
    <Setter Property="Height"
            Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="Padding"
            Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="Red" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                               Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                               Fill="Green" />
                    <Ellipse Width="10"
                             Height="10"
                             Fill="Red"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="CustomRepeatButtonStyle"
       TargetType="RepeatButton">
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="Orange" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
            Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="controls:ControlsHelper.CornerRadius"
            Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="controls:ItemHelper.HoverBackgroundBrush"
            Value="Orange" />
    <Setter Property="controls:ItemHelper.HoverSelectedBackgroundBrush"
            Value="Orange" />
    <Setter Property="controls:ItemHelper.SelectedBackgroundBrush"
            Value="Orange" />
    <Setter Property="controls:ItemHelper.ActiveSelectionBackgroundBrush"
            Value="Orange" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused"
                 Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="Orange" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                 Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="Orange" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

I'm not able to change the background color when I hover the two Repeat Button:

(here's the right one is hovered with Mouse). I want "red" instead of that default blue. Which property do I need to use? The ones I've tried above seems to not have any result.
Any clues?

Dont use Metro, but I am sure you can deconstruct the style in blender and reassign the value you want in the style. Most likely they have a static resource for that, which can you apply application wise as well

@Demon the question is: which property? Tried lots of them, without lucky

can you elaborate what exactly are you trying to archive? you want during RepeadButton Mouse Over event that both buttons would change the background color? Then how it is related to Metro nuget?

@Demon I've added a comment to your answer. Hope now you got what I need (in the screenshot, without hover both repeat button left/right are orange, on hover blue: i want to remove the blue and keep always orange). Hope you can help me!

I will assume you want both repeat buttons to change the border colors whenever you have Mouse Enter value as true. I have used the general styles and not extended yours, so keep that in mind. What I will post is absolutely overkill, but I hope that will clarify many things for you. I tested the Horizontal Slider only and based on your desciption it is the result you wanted. The code contains the vertical slider as well, but you can modify this template as you see fit. Hope that will help you
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="RepeatButtonTransparent" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderThumb.Static.Background" Color="#FFF0F0F0"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderThumb.Static.Border" Color="#FFACACAC"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderThumb.Static.Foreground" Color="#FFE5E5E5"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderThumb.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFDCECFC"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderThumb.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF7Eb4EA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderThumb.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFDAECFC"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderThumb.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderThumb.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF0F0F0"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderThumb.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFD9D9D9"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderThumb.Track.Background" Color="#FFE7EAEA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderThumb.Track.Border" Color="#FFD6D6D6"/>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="SliderThumbHorizontalDefault" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" UseLayoutRounding="True" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Path x:Name="grip" Data="M 0,0 C0,0 11,0 11,0 11,0 11,18 11,18 11,18 0,18 0,18 0,18 0,0 0,0 z" Fill="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Static.Background}" Stroke="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Static.Border}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="1" UseLayoutRounding="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.MouseOver.Border}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsDragging" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Pressed.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Pressed.Border}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Disabled.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Disabled.Border}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="SliderThumbHorizontalTop" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" UseLayoutRounding="True" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Path x:Name="grip" Data="M 0,6 C0,6 5.5,0 5.5,0 5.5,0 11,6 11,6 11,6 11,18 11,18 11,18 0,18 0,18 0,18 0,6 0,6 z" Fill="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Static.Background}" Stroke="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Static.Border}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="1" UseLayoutRounding="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.MouseOver.Border}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsDragging" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Pressed.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Pressed.Border}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Disabled.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Disabled.Border}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="SliderThumbHorizontalBottom" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" UseLayoutRounding="True" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Path x:Name="grip" Data="M 0,12 C0,12 5.5,18 5.5,18 5.5,18 11,12 11,12 11,12 11,0 11,0 11,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,12 0,12 z" Fill="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Static.Background}" Stroke="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Static.Border}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="1" UseLayoutRounding="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.MouseOver.Border}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsDragging" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Pressed.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Pressed.Border}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Disabled.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Disabled.Border}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="SliderHorizontal" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
        <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TickBar x:Name="TopTick" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Height="4" Margin="0,0,0,2" Placement="Top" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                <TickBar x:Name="BottomTick" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Height="4" Margin="0,2,0,0" Placement="Bottom" Grid.Row="2" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                <Border x:Name="TrackBackground" 
                     Background="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Track.Background}"
                     BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                     BorderThickness="1" Height="4.0" Margin="5,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="center">
                    <Canvas Margin="-6,-1">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="PART_SelectionRange" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" Height="4.0" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                    </Canvas>
                </Border>
                <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="1">
                    <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                        <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.DecreaseLarge}" Style="{StaticResource RepeatButtonTransparent}"/>
                    </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                        <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.IncreaseLarge}" Style="{StaticResource RepeatButtonTransparent}"/>
                    </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                    <Track.Thumb>
                        <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Focusable="False" Height="18" OverridesDefaultStyle="True" Template="{StaticResource SliderThumbHorizontalDefault}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="11"/>
                    </Track.Thumb>
                </Track>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="TopLeft">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="TopTick" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="Template" TargetName="Thumb" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbHorizontalTop}"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="TrackBackground" Value="5,2,5,0"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="BottomRight">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="BottomTick" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="Template" TargetName="Thumb" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbHorizontalBottom}"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="TrackBackground" Value="5,0,5,2"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="Both">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="TopTick" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="BottomTick" Value="Visible"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelectionRangeEnabled" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="PART_SelectionRange" Value="Visible"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="Thumb" Value="Blue"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="TrackBackground"  Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="TrackBackground"  Value="Red"/>
            </Trigger>
           
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="SliderThumbVerticalDefault" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" UseLayoutRounding="True" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Path x:Name="grip" Data="M0.5,0.5 L18.5,0.5 18.5,11.5 0.5,11.5z" Fill="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Static.Background}" Stroke="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Static.Border}" Stretch="Fill"/>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.MouseOver.Border}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsDragging" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Pressed.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Pressed.Border}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Disabled.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Disabled.Border}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="SliderThumbVerticalLeft" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" UseLayoutRounding="True" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Path x:Name="grip" Data="M 6,11 C6,11 0,5.5 0,5.5 0,5.5 6,0 6,0 6,0 18,0 18,0 18,0 18,11 18,11 18,11 6,11 6,11 z" Fill="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Static.Background}" Stroke="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Static.Border}" Stretch="Fill"/>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.MouseOver.Border}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsDragging" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Pressed.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Pressed.Border}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Disabled.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Disabled.Border}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="SliderThumbVerticalRight" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" UseLayoutRounding="True" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Path x:Name="grip" Data="M 12,11 C12,11 18,5.5 18,5.5 18,5.5 12,0 12,0 12,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,11 0,11 0,11 12,11 12,11 z" Fill="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Static.Background}" Stroke="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Static.Border}" Stretch="Fill"/>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.MouseOver.Border}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsDragging" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Pressed.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Pressed.Border}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Disabled.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Disabled.Border}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="SliderVertical" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
        <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}" Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TickBar x:Name="TopTick" Grid.Column="0" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Margin="0,0,2,0" Placement="Left" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="4"/>
                <TickBar x:Name="BottomTick" Grid.Column="2" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Margin="2,0,0,0" Placement="Right" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="4"/>
                <Border x:Name="TrackBackground" Background="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Track.Background}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Track.Border}" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="center" Margin="0,5" Width="4.0">
                    <Canvas Margin="-1,-6">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="PART_SelectionRange" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"
                                Visibility="Hidden" Width="4.0"/>
                    </Canvas>
                </Border>
                <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Column="1">
                    <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                        <RepeatButton  Command="{x:Static Slider.DecreaseLarge}" Style="{StaticResource RepeatButtonTransparent}"/>
                    </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                        <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.IncreaseLarge}" Style="{StaticResource RepeatButtonTransparent}"/>
                    </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                    <Track.Thumb>
                        <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Focusable="False" Height="20" OverridesDefaultStyle="True" Template="{StaticResource SliderThumbVerticalDefault}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="18"/>
                    </Track.Thumb>
                </Track>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="TopLeft">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="TopTick" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="Template" TargetName="Thumb" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbVerticalLeft}"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="TrackBackground" Value="2,5,0,5"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="BottomRight">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="BottomTick" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="Template" TargetName="Thumb" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbVerticalRight}"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="TrackBackground" Value="0,5,2,5"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="Both">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="TopTick" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="BottomTick" Value="Visible"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelectionRangeEnabled" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="PART_SelectionRange" Value="Visible"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="Thumb" Value="Blue"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="SliderStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Static.Foreground}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource SliderHorizontal}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource SliderVertical}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Slider Style="{DynamicResource SliderStyle1}" x:Name="videoPlayerSlider"
 Minimum="0"
 Maximum="100"
 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
 VerticalAlignment="Center"
 Value="50"
 Height="20">
</Slider>

Update:
the core idea is to overwrite StaticResource with TemplateBinding in your buttons so you can manipulate it.
Example based on your code:
<Style x:Key="CustomRepeatButtonStyle"
TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
<Setter Property="Background"
Value="#d1cbcb" />
<Setter Property="BorderThickness"
Value="0" />
<Setter Property="controls:ControlsHelper.CornerRadius"
Value="0" />
<Setter Property="Template">
<Setter.Value>
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
<Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" />
</ControlTemplate>
</Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="CustomRepeatButtonStyleLeft"
TargetType="RepeatButton"
BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type RepeatButton}}">
<Setter Property="Background"
Value="#81b3d4" />
<Setter Property="Template">
<Setter.Value>
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
<Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" />
</ControlTemplate>
</Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>


I mean, when I hover the Repeat Button (whatever the one on the left, or the right), the background color become "blue", and doesn't keep orange (as it is when it is not overed). Is it more clear now?

Have you checked the solution i provided? When you hover over the repeat button here, both (left and right) will change color. the color assignment the IsMouseOver trigger in the SliderStyle

This means review the whole Slider control. What I'm asking is if thats possible ONLY to override the two RepeatButton...

@markzzz without overriding the slider template it would not be possible (at least to my knowledge), this is because default control template does not, since you have to reassign BorderBrush from StaticResource to Template, so you can manipulate it from outside of the control (from  BorderBrush="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Track.Border}" into    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" ) that way you can use triggers within the style of the slider itself, same with background

It doesnt compile. First think, it seems there is a nested style.triggers. Later, it says I cannot set property Template in the current template element...

@markzzz just edited the template

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
